# getting multiple NPE's on ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()

Tags: android, android-layout

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3069)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchDraw(PhoneWindow.java:2387)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13580)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1627)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1506)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2728)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2593)
```

while searching for this , i found that it only happens when we change layouts/view in onAnimationEnd(). Here is my onAnimationEnd()...

```
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        if(productList != null)
                            productList.bringToFront();
                        if(toggleView != null)
                            toggleView.bringToFront();
                        if(footerView != null)
                            footerView.bringToFront();
                        if(headerView != null) {
                            headerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            headerView.clearAnimation();
                        }
                    }
```

I haven't change any view or layout but still getting lot of these errors

Comment: Usually when you see this, you will see multiple stack traces next to each other (basically one exception causes another).  Its the bottom one that matters.